# Why does exposure shift occur with my OM-D EM-5?

Tags: troubleshooting, olympus-omd

I have been using OM-D Em-5 for a few months with my 3 lenses: 12mm f/2, panasonic 25mm f/1.4 and 45mm f/1.8. Two of my lenses have a problem with exposure shift all the time - after I turn camera on, first picture I get will be completely black or when I change ISO or aperture and even the screen show bright images.

I have tried to update body firmware, which is up to date. But the lens description seems like a problem - they don't show the name of the lens but show ---- instead in version 1.00.

Does anyone know what is happening with my camera or lenses? And how can I fix them?

Comment: Is the problem really "exposure shift", or is it "first frame after I turn the camera on is entirely black"?

Answer (score 2):

This thread has a number of people describing very similar issues: http://www.flickr.com/groups/om-d_user/discuss/72157630018014187/

There is some info on there that looks like it might help you:

- "If you are able to turn on/wake up the camera, wait 15 sec, and still get a dark frame on your first shot, then I'd say your camera has an "issue," even if it only happens intermittently." .. "either exchange it or send it  in for warranty service"
- "I have the same issue on my E-M5, and it seems to happen more with the 45mm."
- "Olympus confirmed that the issue was with my shutter when they replaced the mechanism and sent it back to me. No problems since then. Its possible that a couple of batches were affected with this problem."
- "The issue was not with the aperture but with the shutter itself. it was sticking, and was not performing to spec on fast shutter speeds (usually anything faster than 1/1000)"

Lots of people asked whether bracketing had been left on!